# Create new category upon save based on post information

Tags: posts, php, custom-taxonomy

After finding a couple of leads on how to do this, I'm coming up blank. What I am trying to accomplish is to add the post to a new category based on camera name. If the category doesn't exist, then to create it and add.

Essentially what I have below grabs the attachment meta information and saves the camera information into $camera. From there, it kind of falls apart.

```
function add_post_camera_category() {
global $post;
global $wpdb;
    // Load array with attachment information
    if (is_null($imgID)) {
        $images = get_children(array(
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'ASC'
            ));
        if ($images) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $imgID = $image->ID;
            }
        }
    }

    $imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($imgID);
if ($imgmeta)
{
    if ($imgmeta['image_meta']['camera'])
        $camera = $imgmeta['image_meta']['camera'];

            // Add to custom category
        if(!has_term('','category',$post_ID)){
            $category = get_term_by( 'slug', $camera, 'category' );
            $cat = array($category->slug);
            wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category');
        }

}

}
add_action('save_post', 'add_post_camera_category');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some comments on your code:

- the globals `$post` and `$wpdb` are not needed, in any case you can declare them as `global $post, $wpdb;`
- I don't understand your use of this conditional `if (is_null($imgID))`
- you're using `get_term_by` with "slug", but I guess it's better to do it by "name"

The following is a working code, but I'm not sure if there are any flaws in it. As I was not able to debug the `save_post` using FirePHP, I did a dirty trick dumping the vars inside a custom field: `update_post_meta($post_ID, 'cf_debug_info', print_r($imgmeta,true));`.

```
add_action('save_post', 'wpse_53549_add_post_camera_category', 10, 2);

function wpse_53549_add_post_camera_category($post_ID, $post) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    $images = get_children( array(
        'post_parent' => $post_ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));

    if ( $images ) 
    {
        $image = array_shift( $images );
        $imgID = $image->ID;
    }

    if ( !$imgID ) 
            return;

    $imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($imgID);

    if ( $imgmeta )
    {
        // this info may be useful when checking for has_term
        // $defaultcat = get_option('default_category');

        $camera = ($imgmeta['image_meta']['camera']) ? $imgmeta['image_meta']['camera'] : false;        

        if ( $camera )

            // Add to custom category
            if( !has_term( $camera, 'category', $post_ID ) )
            {
                $category = get_term_by( 'name', $camera, 'category' );
                if ( $category )
                {
                    $cat = array( $category->slug );
                    // the last parameter sets if the term must be appended or overwrite the previous
                    wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $cat, 'category', true );
                }
                else
                {
                    $id = wp_create_category( $camera );
                    $new_cat = get_term_by( 'id', $id, 'category' );
                    wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $new_cat->slug, 'category', true );
                }
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly!

Comment: Bravo! As a photographer I really enjoyed grabbing all those `image_meta` and seeing the categories magically created with the Camera names (& downloaded samples from different cameras for testing the code:).

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to incorporate it into my theme. So it will say Camera: Canon 5D Mark II, and have that as a link to the Canon 5D2 category. Since the camera meta itself isn't a link, and I want it to link to the correct category using only the camera name, maybe I need to do a fancy category call to strip down the 1 category based on $camera?

Comment: Ain't this just a matter of having a parent category `Cameras` and using [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)??

Comment: Sure, it could be. But on my site, I list out exif information and geotag locations. So rather than blindly listing all categories, I plan on making it "smart" and displaying only the category link for the camera that was used to take the photo displayed.

Comment: Got it. But I guess this is a topic for a brand new Q!

Comment: Sure would be if I get stuck... until then, I'll continue to tinker!

Answer (score 1):

You use $post->ID to get the image data and then you use $post_ID to save your term data. I don't think $post_ID is defined.

I usually take the post ID from the function call 
Maybe it should be:
function add_post_camera_category($post_ID) {

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post