# Save camera info as metadata on image upload?

Tags: uploads, post-meta

I am trying to have WordPress automatically save the "credit" metadata that is stored within images I am uploading. I know this would be entered as a custom post meta field using [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).

The "credit" information is gathered by [`wp_read_image_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_image_metadata), but [`media_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) doesn't use it. It only uses the "caption" and "title" information gathered from the image for `post_content` and `post_title` respectively.

I've found several examples of how to add custom attachment metadata fields **after** the upload when editing the image, but since WP is already gathering this information from the image's metadata, I'd like to find a way to have it saved as the image is uploaded.

I'm unclear of what steps to take to hook into [`media_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) (there doesn't seem to be a hook) so that I can call `update_post_meta` to save the "credit" line for the attachment.

Comment: This is a great question, I will try and answer it when I have time or add a bounty to it. I did try for 15 minutes and it produced some amazingly detailed errors like "an error occurred in the upload. Please try again later", even though it was working.

Comment: Hey @Wyck, indeed a great Q, I guess I was working on it at the same time ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata):

> This function generates metadata for an image attachment. It also creates a thumbnail and other intermediate sizes of the image attachment based on the sizes defined on the Settings_Media_Screen.

The second argument of the filter is the attachment ID, so it shouldn't be a problem to add the post meta:

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'manipulate_metadata_wpse_91177', 10, 2 );

function manipulate_metadata_wpse_91177( $metadata, $attachment_id ) 
{
    // var_dump( $metadata['image_meta'] );
    // Credit is inside $metadata['image_meta']['credit']
    return $metadata;
}
```

Inspecting the contents of `$metadata['image_meta']` with FirePHP, these are the results:

```
aperture: 4
camera: "DMC-FZ100"
caption: ""
copyright: ""
created_timestamp: 1352136868
credit: ""
focal_length: "9.2"
iso: "100"
shutter_speed: "0.003125"
title: "Double Dip"
```

---

**[Update]**
Full test adding a custom column in Media Library screen (`/wp-admin/upload.php`) to display the post meta info:

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'manipulate_metadata_wpse_91177', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'manage_upload_columns', 'camera_info_column_wpse_91177' );
add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'camera_info_display_wpse_91177', 10, 2 );

function manipulate_metadata_wpse_91177( $metadata, $attachment_id ) 
{
    update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'photo_title', $metadata['image_meta']['title'] );
    update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'photo_camera', $metadata['image_meta']['camera'] );
    return $metadata;
}

function camera_info_column_wpse_91177( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['cam_info'] = 'Camera Info';    
    return $columns;
}

function camera_info_display_wpse_91177( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    if( 'cam_info' != $column_name || !wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'photo_title', true );
    $camera = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'photo_camera', true );
    $echo_title = $title ? 'Title: ' . $title . '<br />' : '';
    $echo_camera = $camera ? 'Camera: ' . $camera : '';
    echo $echo_title . $echo_camera;
}
```

### [image: camera info]

Somewhat related Q&A: [Create new category upon save based on post information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53549/12615)

Comment: I think I mis-understood the question thankfully you answered, I was trying to set the "credit" field in the media box section so it could be altered by the end user if they wanted to change it from what the exif said..phew..

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks again. On a side note, why does $attachment_id have to be the second argument on the filter? It doesn't work if it's the first argument. I wasn't able to find clarification in the add_filter docs.

Comment: @user955664, that's [The Way of the Hook](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L118) or [Follow the Source, Luke](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html)!

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks, again. It makes sense when looking at the apply_filters call to wp_generate_attachment_metadata. I had been looking at the function itself, not the apply_filters call.